# Form submission not working in Django 1.11 with python 2.7

Tags: python, django

Am new to Django . I have python2.7 and django 1.11 version , I was able to display a home page etc. But when trying to create a form and submitting its not redirecting to any page

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
    
urlpatterns = [
    url("",views.home, name="home"),
    url("add",views.add,name="add")
]
```

home.html

```
{%extends 'base.html' %}
{%block content %}

<H1>  hello world 2 {{name}} </H2>

<form action="/add">
    Enter 1st number : <input type="text" name = "num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number : <input type="text" name = "num2"><br>
<input type = "submit">
</form>
```

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    x = ' Hello World'
    return render(request,'home.html',{'name' : 'Test  Name'} )
    # return HttpResponse(x)
def add(request):
    print('testing')
    val1 = request.GET['num1']
    val2 = request.GET['num2']
    res = val1 + val2
    print(res)
    return render(request,"results.html",{'result' : res})
```

results.html  is a test page. Once I click submit its not displaying any thing on the results page . Is there anything wrong in url.py

Comment: Could you show use your ```results.html``` template?

Comment: Do you get the output from the calls to `print`? And what does `results.html` look like? It might be even more broken than your `home.html` (opening tag `H1`, closing tag `H2`)

Comment: What if you rewrite `type =  "submit"` to `type="submit"`, etc? I'm not sure the spacing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely certain, but I'm guessing it has to do with how your URLs are being declared. Specifically your url for "/add/".

I read through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example and it seems that treating the url path as a regex is important. I also believe that the trailing slash is important - I'd certainly try adding it since that might very well be your problem.

```py
    url(r"^add/$",views.add,name="add")
```